# SqlDataReader returns null unexpectedly

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a simple connection to a SQL Server that is not working. I'm trying to read data from it using a `SqlDataReader` in C#.

Here is the code:

```
bool ok = false;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"********";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", uname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", pass);
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT username FROM admins WHERE pass='@b'";
cmd.Connection = con;

SqlDataReader r;

con.Open();
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
r.Read();

string n;
n = r.GetString(0);

if (n != null)
{
    ok = true;
}

con.Close();

if (ok)
{
    Session["admin"] = uname;
    Response.Redirect("admin_page.aspx");
}
else
{
    eror.Text = "An eror occured";
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx#work");
}
```

Note: that in the above code string "uname" and "pass" are definitely not null.

Note #2 : I did try running the `r.read()` in a while loop (even though it's not possible to have more then one row) ---> same result.

I tried running this code in step mode, and it appears that it breaks on this line:

```
n = r.GetString(0);
```

With this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I'm kinda lost here. I know that it's probably a simple thing I missed here, I just can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: `@a` is not even used in your query, and your problem is that now rows are returned so you get ***Invalid attempt to read when no data is present***

Comment: Couple of things. Why do you have parameter @a when you don't use it? Also, if you add parameters you shouldn't add the ' characters manually to your query. It will be taken care of automatically.  You should test if r.Read succeeds (use the return value), if it doesn't your data isn't found in the database. I suspect that this is the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Amit's observation about an unused parameter, you are misusing the parameter

Where you have

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT username FROM admins WHERE pass='@b'";
```

you should not have quotes around the value, so:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT username FROM admins WHERE pass=@b";
```

The parameter will know it is a VARCHAR

Comment: Removing the quotes around the value solved it. thanks alot.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  Note that Amit's answer goes further (gives you information for which you didn't even ask), explaining how to better use the query result  in your use case.  I suggest you accept his answer so the question is marked answered!

Comment: @user3107990: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Your not using `SqlDataReader` correctly.

If you want to know whether there exists a user with the correct username and password, your query should probably be: `SELECT 1 FROM admins WHERE username=@a AND pass=@b`

Once that's done, and since you don't care what the selected value is (you only care that there was a returned row...) Use the command like this:

```
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ok = r.HasRows;
```

After this, continue as you did.